# How to randomize an array with objects

Tags: javascript

I have a simple div that should play random sounds onclick. I store my sounds inside an array of objects like this:

```
var sounds = [
  {
    animalType: 'horse',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Horse-neigh.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'bear',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/grizzlybear.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'goat',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Goat-noise.mp3'),
  }
]
```

Then when I randomize it it gives me this error: `sound.play is not a function`

here is my attempt at randomizing it:

```
 var player = document.getElementById('player');

 player.addEventListener('click', function() 
 var sound = sounds.sort( () => Math.random() - 0.5)
 sound.play()
})
```

Why is it giving me this error and how can I make it work? It works when it's only an array, but when using an array with objects it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDIT] I've made a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/35xmu0ec/).

It's simpler to randomize the index of your array of sounds. Example below:

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');

player.addEventListener('click', function() 
    var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)]; 
    sound['sound'].play() //acessing "sound" element from your randomized object
})
```

Comment: yes I tried that variant first and it still gives me sound.play is not a function

Comment: Now I've figured it out. Your array have objects, and the sound is in the "sound" element. Changed my answer. Try it!

Answer (score 2):

Don't randomize the order of the list, just choose a random number from the possible range of indices for the list. Then adjust the behavior accordingly to make sure it isn't playing the same sound again and again (since it's a small list, that'll likely happen).

Comment: Just what I was thinking about. There is no point in randomizing the whole list, it's better to generate a random number and use it as an index. Then store the numbers that have been generated and if the newly generated number matches any of these you simply generate another.

Answer (score 0):

Because `sound` does not contain one of the objects but instead the entire array.

Try `sound[0]` to pick an actual sound object :)

Answer (score 0):

using `.sort` on an array does not return a single element of that array but it returns an array of all the elements ( sorted ). You were expecting `.sort` to return a single element from the array. [mdn sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

What you need is

```
 var animal = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)]

if ( ! animal ) {
   sounds[0].sound.play();
} else {
   animal.sound.play()
}
```

the reason for `!animal` is for a situation wereby `Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)` goes out of the sounds array bound

Comment: It still gives that animal.sound is not a function

Comment: I do not think it possible for `Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)` to evaluate do an index out of bound of the `sounds` array. The resulting index is in the interval `[0, sounds.length[`. This can only happen if the array is mutated at some point...

Comment: @PierreC. thanks for the edit and informing me about this :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation you have 1 bug in your above use below code let me know if you still get same error:

```
var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
sound.play()
```

or

```
var sound = sounds.sort( () => Math.random() - 0.5),
sound.play()
```

Error is at randomize{ **() => Mth.random() - 0.5** } process if still you won't get check by eliminating random function....